# Aggregating over two columns (sum and min)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Given is the following dataframe:

```
name    item        price   timestamp
______________________________________
Elliot   a            10        12312
Sara     b            20        45654
Elliot   a            30        15000
Tom      a            5         43423
```

Elliot, for example, consumed item 'a' twice, and now I want to aggregate over all such cases such that in the end I have only a single occurrence of 'name-item' pair, but such that the 'price' is summed and the 'timestamp' corresponds to the minimum found:

```
name    item        price   timestamp
______________________________________
Elliot   a            40        12312
Sara     b            20        45654
Tom      a            5         43423
```

How can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby.agg` which takes a dictionary with your column names as `keys` and operations as `values`.

```
calcs = {'item':'first','price':'sum','timestamp':'min'}
df.groupby('name').agg(calcs).reset_index()
```

which prints:

```
     name item  price  timestamp
0  Elliot    a     40      12312
1    Sara    b     20      45654
2     Tom    a      5      43423
```

You can also use [`Named.Agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) where you control the output names with different aggregations per column, as below:

```
>>> df.groupby('name').agg( 
    total_price_per_customer=pd.NamedAgg(column='price', aggfunc='sum'), 
    minimum_timestamp_per_customer=pd.NamedAgg(column='timestamp', aggfunc='min'))

        total_price_per_customer  minimum_timestamp_per_customer
name                                                            
Elliot                        40                           12312
Sara                          20                           45654
Tom                            5                           43423
```

Comment: Could you add the 'item' column into play?

Comment: Yes you can. I updated the answer and you can easily change the 2nd part too. I think ```first``` should cover you in this example, but please consider what aggregation you would like on your item column.

Comment: But why is the number of columns via df.shape now different, although df.head shows all four columns?

Comment: Because your ```name``` column has become the ```index```.  Add a ```reset_index()``` at the end of your ```groupby``` statement - also updated the answer to show that.